# Gunzip buffer and write into a file

Tags: node.js, zlib

I am reading a file from AWS S3 where I stored a gzipped file and in Nodejs I am creating an endpoint to download, unzip and write into a file to serve it. 
I am using Nodejs Zlib module to decompress but I am getting this error while unzipping.
I am getting the data from AWS as Buffer in data.Body

```
Error decompressing::  Error: incorrect header check
    at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (zlib.js:168:17) {
    errno: -3,
    code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR'
```

The code for decompressing is:

```
S3Client.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
    if(err) {
        error('Error getting Object:: ', err);
    } else {
        zlib.gunzip(data.Body, (err, buff) => {
            if(err) {
                error('Error decompressing:: ', err);
            } else {
                fs.writeFileSync('folder/'+name+'.mht', buff);
            }
        })
    }
})
```